# Object_hook in json module doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: python, json, deserialization, python-3.6

I have:

```
def decoder(o):
  return o.get("fruits")


array = '{"fruits": [{"apple": "red"}, {"banana": "yellow"}, "orange"]}'
data  = json.loads(array, object_hook=decoder)
print(data)
```

This is returning `[None, None, 'orange']`.

However, if I do something like below without using object_hook

```
n = json.loads(array)
print(n.get("fruits"))
```

This returns `[{'apple': 'red'}, {'banana': 'yellow'}, 'orange']` as desired.

How can I use object_hook to return `[{'apple': 'red'}, {'banana': 'yellow'}, 'orange']` instead of `[None, None, 'orange']`?  What part of my code is causing it to return None?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `object_hook` will be used instead of the `dict`

`Notice: return value of object_hook would replace all dict object in your json string`

```
# the reason you get None: 

# 1 inner dict {"apple": "red"} apply "object_hook" 
# 2 return o.get("fruits") --> None
```

You can try with below codes for your reference:

```
import json


def decoder(o):
    if o.get("fruits"):
        return o["fruits"]
    return o


array = '{"fruits": [{"apple": "red"}, {"banana": "yellow"}, "orange"]}'
data = json.loads(array, object_hook=decoder)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This helps a lot.

Comment: You are welcome and you can accept the answer if it useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to understand what happens is to print `o`:

```
{'apple': 'red'}
{'banana': 'yellow'}
{'fruits': [None, None, 'orange']}
[None, None, 'orange']
```

Now it seems the mystery is solved. As for how to solve it with I don't think it should be used like that. You can of course keep the code you currently have and then filter the list for all element that are not `None` like:

```py
result_list = [x if x is not None for x in result_list]
```

Where `result_list` stores the values from `json.loads`

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand what was going on.